# Spring Security: CookieTheftException with PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a web application with spring-boot 2.0.1 protected by spring-security. I use a `PersistentTokenRepository` for Remember-Me and store the tokens in a MySQL database.

In the server logfiles I see quite a lot of stacktraces with `CookieTheftException`s. It's so many that I find it hard to believe that actual Cookies are stolen but assume some kind of misconfiguration. From adding some analyzing code, it seems only mobile browsers are affected.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/r] threw exception
  org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.CookieTheftException: Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch. Implies previous cookie theft attack.
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Manual testing was not able to reproduce this. Deleting the session cookie, but keeping the remember-me Cookie and making a request to a restricted URL leads to a normal authenticated session.

Here are the relevant parts of my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Configuration
    public static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .rememberMe()
                    .key(rememberMeKey)
                    .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices);
            ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Key for RememberMeServices and RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.
     */
    private static final String rememberMeKey = "...";

    @Bean
    public RememberMeServices rememberMeServices(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository) {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new AnalyzingPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                rememberMeKey, userDetailsService, persistentTokenRepository);
        rememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds((int) Duration.of(366L, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toSeconds());
        return rememberMeServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        return tokenRepository;
    }
}
```

That `AnalyzingPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` is a `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` with some additional logging in `processAutoLoginCookie`.

Another speciality is, that I use a custom `AuthenticationProvider`, and provide a `UserDetailsService` only for RememberMe. But as said above, manual testing works just fine. Still, users report they get logged out too often (session timeout is 24 hours).

Did anybody experience something like this and has a solution? Do I miss some crucial configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` is not suitable for applications with concurrent requests, which might send the same token series.

See these almost five year old and unresolved bug reports:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2648

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3079

Using `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` does not have those problems.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. In most cases people chose PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices because TokenBasedRememberMeServices was not suitable to begin with. Namely it is not as secure.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Redisson to implement distributed locking and a distributed map to hold a fast-expiring cache, enabling the first-arriving request of a batch of concurrent requests to renew the token and allowing the soon-to-follow requests to be aware that the token had recently refreshed and use that new value.

Answer (score 0):

In spring security web 4.2.13 implementation problem in mechanism of token prolongation

```
protected UserDetails processAutoLoginCookie(String[] cookieTokens,...
  .....
    PersistentRememberMeToken newToken = new PersistentRememberMeToken(
            token.getUsername(), token.getSeries(), generateTokenData(), new Date());

    try {
        tokenRepository.updateToken(newToken.getSeries(), newToken.getTokenValue(),
                newToken.getDate());
        addCookie(newToken, request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to update token: ", e);
        throw new RememberMeAuthenticationException(
                "Autologin failed due to data access problem");
    }
```

During refreshing in case of concurrent request token value for same series can be rewritten in DB few times, but in cookie can be saved another value.

The token creation during login works well, in worst case u can have many persisted tokens in DB, but one of them will work =)

In my project I have fix bug by modification of refresh algorithm:

```
   if (token.date + 1 < new Date()){
       try {
            PersistentRememberMeToken newToken = new PersistentRememberMeToken( token.getUsername(), generateSeriesData(), generateTokenData(), new Date())
            tokenRepository.createNewToken(newToken)
            addCookie(newToken, request, response)
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to update token: ", e);
            throw new RememberMeAuthenticationException(
                    "Autologin failed due to data access problem");
        }
    }
```

This code produce many DB records at result, but works